# Is ther a way to use MSBuild inside an application's code to build another application

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I want to build an application (app A) that builds another application (app B) and that edits the .proj file for compiling (.proj of app B). 
I am familiar with MSbuild but I wonder if there is a way of using it inside my code to compile the app. I want the customer to customize the build settings and to get the latest libraries he wants from a a team foundation server. I really need a good place to start with this.

Comment: Maybe you can execute a batch file?

Comment: To build a project, you just need one execution of `MSBuild`. So why don't you just start a process using `Process.Start()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Microsoft.Build](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145008.aspx) namespaces contain types that provide programmatic access to, and control of, the MSBuild engine.

Comment: Specifically, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project and the Build method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd234361.aspx